# angular 2 System.import issue

Tags: angular, webpack

I have that code that works fine with SystemJS.
Now I moved my angular 2 project to webpack and the System.import failled.

Any ideea? Thank you!

```
private loadBundles(fullBundlesFilePath:any, callback?: any) {
        System.import(fullBundlesFilePath).then((bundles:any) => {
            bundles.forEach((bundleUrl:any) => this.loadBundle(bundleUrl, callback));
        });
    }
```

the content of the file that want to be loaded is

```
module.exports = function () {
    return [
        '/explorerweb_bundles/login/manifest.js',
        '/explorerweb_bundles/printers/manifest.js' 
    ];
}() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to pass a variable to import in webpack. Webpack needs to know what modules to include in the bundle at compile time, and as it does no program flow analysis it won't know which ones to include. Additionally import doesn't take an array, but just one module. So you need to do it manually, like so:

```
System.import('/explorerweb_bundles/login/manifest.js').then(module => /*...*/);
System.import('/explorerweb_bundles/printers/manifest.js').then(module => /*...*/);
```

On a side note [`System.import` is deprecated](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-import/#system-import-is-deprecated) in favour of `import()`.

Comment: So, it is not possible to pass an external url to System.import on angular-cli application to load an umd library?
The only way to load the library is through an application created exclusively with systemjs? @michale-jungo

Comment: Is it possible to integrate systemjs with webpack?